# How to update third party widgets at BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: java, android, widget

In my app the user can pick a widget from all widgets installed on the system and add it to a view.

If i start my app before booting of the device has completed, the widgets are not updated. If i wait until booting has completed and start then, it works.

Since these widgets are not my own ones, i dont have access to their WidgetProvider and cant update them when the event "BOOT_COMPLETED" happens.

How could i update them anyway (if even possible) ?

**Update:**

i tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

in onReceive of BOOT_COMPLETED-BroadcastReceiver. Unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending `"android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"` as broadcast once you received BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: thank you, could you be more precise how that would look like?

Comment: "context.sendBroadcast("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");" is not a valid expression since sendBroadcast doesnt accept a String. I added to my question what i tried. Not working though

Comment: try context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"));

Comment: doesnt work either. Maybe this only works on widgets on home-screen?

Answer (score 0):

For who have problems with the widget that don’t update itself after the boot I suggest to move startListening and stopListening methods in onCreate and onDestroy as reported here http://selvaline.blogspot.it/2015/10/hosting-widgets-and-regurally-update.html

```
onCreate:
        mAppWidgetHost.startListening();

onDestroy:
        mAppWidgetHost.stopListening();
```